# Sharepoint REST API authentication with SAML

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

My app uses OKTA for authentication using SAML. I was able to get this up. I am also able to make REST calls to sharepoint using the username and password.

Now that I have both these set up, I would like to integrate them. I would like to use OKTA(SAML) for authentication and then would like to use the SAML token for authentication of REST calls.

I would like to know if Sharepoint REST API supports it and if yes what headers should I pass for the same.

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint Online uses a token based authentication mechanism. To authenticate with SharePoint Online you can use an active or passive approach. Active involves calling a web service to authenticate with and receive a token in return. Passive makes use of a web browser control from which you can then retrieve the security token from the cookies.

The token is then associated with each call you make to SharePoint Online.

Check these.

[Authentication with SharePoint Online and the Client Side Object Model](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cjohnson/archive/2011/05/03/authentication-with-sharepoint-online-and-the-client-side-object-model.aspx)

[Remote Authentication in SharePoint Online Using Claims-Based Authentication](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh147177.aspx)

[Part 2: “Headless” Authentication with SharePoint Online and the Client Side Object Model](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cjohnson/archive/2011/05/14/part-2-headless-authentication-with-sharepoint-online-and-the-client-side-object-model.aspx)

https://github.com/OfficeDev/PnP/blob/2f91e2d053171d2e9bb6a60fc0f7004401ffc363/OfficeDevPnP.Core/SAML%20authentication.md